# How to convert dict containing tuple values to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How to convert the following Input to the desired output using python.

Input:

```
{'Id': (34,), 'user': ('a.t@gmail.com',), 'createdOn': ('12 Oct',), 'status': (False,), 'message': ('Hello',)}
```

Output:

```
{'Id': 34, 'user': 'a.t@gmail.com', 'createdOn':'12 Oct', 'status': False, 'message': 'Hello'}
```

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: Many ways, e.g, use map: `dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][0]), d.items()))`.

Comment: Chances are, if you're getting this from something like a `MultiValueDict`, there's a different method on it you can call to not get tuples to begin with…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are the values in a tuple to begin with?

```
old_dict = {'Id': (34,), 'user': ('a.t@gmail.com',), 'createdOn': ('12 Oct',), 'status': (False,), 'message': ('Hello',)}
new_dict = {k:v[0] for k,v in old_dict.items()}
print(new_dict)
```

Comment: I would guess the OP is fetching rows from a database cursor which returns as a tuple and generating a dict with the data. To me this seems like a XY problem where the original task probably has a better solution

Answer (score 2):

Just take first index for each value :

```py
your_dict = {'Id': (34,), 'user': ('a.t@gmail.com',), 'createdOn': ('12 Oct',), 'status': (False,), 'message': ('Hello',)}
your_dict = {key:val[0] for key, val in your_dict.items()}
```